# Run KQL on data in spark without writing the data to azure data explorer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-data-explorer

I need to run a query over data stored in azure data explorer and on live data being processed by spark. I do not know how to run a KQL query on live data in spark, and the data stored in kusto is too much to load into spark.  Storing the data in kusto and then performing a query would add to much time to processing the data.

Does anyone know how to run a KQL query on live data in spark?

I have tried to create a custom converter to run KQL queries in spark

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [external tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/externaltables) feature that allows you to query data located in storage. Assuming that the data processed by Spark is in storage, this should fit your needs.

Comment: Spark stores the data in ram, thus the data is not in storage

Comment: Then you will need to do the query federation yourself in Spark. You can use the Kusto python SDK to run the applicable Kusto query on the data stored in Kusto and then merge the results with relevant data in the Spark memory, There is no support in Kusto for querying data in Spark memory.